# Highcharts grouped columns of varying widths that fill the entire space automatically

Tags: highcharts

I have this:

[Columns with empty spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXaVa.png)

and i need this:

[Columns without empty spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUiu9.png)

I have hourly data on the first 24 intervals and then tri-hourly data for the following intervals.

I can not find an option for this and I do not want to use the option pointRange because I want to have only one series per column.

Any idea ?

Comment: **Varwide** type of series seems to be what you're looking for: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/variwide

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try this type, but columns are not correctly placed on the corresponding hours https://jsfiddle.net/eightball/wmpfvsLs/. Is there an option for that ?
NB: x must match the beginning of the data range, so the end must be x + z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kamil Kulig, i create a new type from variwide type. variwide type has an odd postTranslate function that distored axis translation and it is not working for me with x-axis datetime.

```
/**
 * Variable width column type
 */
H.seriesType('varicolumn', 'column', {}, {
    init: function () {
        H.seriesTypes.column.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        this.chart.columnCount = (this.chart.columnCount) ? this.chart.columnCount + 1 : 1;
    },
    translate: function () {
        H.seriesTypes.column.prototype.translate.call(this);

        var points = this.points,
            chart = this.chart;

        H.each(points, function (point, i) {
            var lastPoint = points[i - 1],
                nextPoint = points[i + 1],
                shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
                width = (lastPoint) ? point.plotX - lastPoint.plotX : nextPoint.plotX - point.plotX,
                groupingPos = chart.columnCount - point.series.columnIndex;

            shapeArgs.width = width / chart.columnCount;
            shapeArgs.x = Math.round(point.plotX - (shapeArgs.width * groupingPos));
        }, this);
    }
});
```